# Using a reverse tunnel to access a firewall-ed web server serving HTTPS

Tags: ssh, ssl, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I have a device ("A) on my network that only serves content via HTTPS, it's not accessible as its behind my router/firewall.

I have another machine ("B"), elsewhere on the internet (fake IP of 44.44.44.44)

I want to be to access the content being served from A from B.  I have accepted_keys set up on B for A.

--

I have a basic understanding of SSL/TLS tunneling, but I've never complicated it with HTTPS.

So I start with creating a reverse tunnel from A -> B:

```
ssh -N -R 8888:localhost:443 john@44.44.44.44
```

So at this point, on B, I should be able to access port 8888 as if it were 443 on A?

When I try to hit localhost:8888 on B, I get the following (from link2s)

> ```
> Bad request!
>
>    Your browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
>
>    If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 400
>
>     www.example.com
>     Sat Mar 29 22:50:34 2014
>     Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) PHP/5.5.8 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1f DAV/2
> ```

While I'm playing with this, I happen to be using Apache, is there a feature I need to enable in its config or something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ask a browser to connect to `localhost:8888` it will actually default to using `http://localhost:8888/`, which will not work in your case since it is an SSL port. Using the URL `https://localhost:8888/` instead should work, except from the certificate warning.

Comment: Great.  I totally whiffed on the HTTPS:// prefix.

Is there an easy work around for the certificate issue?  I'm guess it's being rejected as it's not signed for 'localhost' at 8888.  Do I have to modify the certification on A to include that?

Comment: If you are fine with getting a warning about a self-signed certificate, then you could just include the additional name in the certificate. If you need a CA signed certificate, then the easiest solution may be to add an entry to /etc/hosts on B and then access the port forwarding by a fully qualified hostname rather than using localhost.

Comment: So I could add the IP for B as a SAN in the self-signed cert?  Or if I use your hosts file suggestion, I just add an entry "thisisb.com" that points to localhost with "thisisb.com" in my non-snakeoil cert?